# Customize caption name of figures

Tags: floats, formatting, captions, naming

I want to produce a figure caption like the following figure.[image]

So I use the following package in the article environment.

```
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont={bf,sf},labelsep=space,figurename=Figure]{caption}
```

However, what I get when I use `\caption{\sffamily{\textbf{Quantum jumps}}}` is
[image]

So, how do I get it to display Figure instead of Fig.? Also, how do I get the | next to Figure 1? When I set labelsep=|, I got an error.

Thanks.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[8.5pt,twoside,twocolumn]{article}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're using a class that isn't compatible with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption), the following should work.

In order to define a `|` separator, use

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{pipe}{ $|$ }% or $\vert$
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{pipe}{ $|$ }% or $\vert$
\captionsetup{
  format=plain,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  font=small,
  font={bf,sf}, % This covers labelfont and textfont
  labelsep=pipe,
  figurename=Figure
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I still got Fig. instead or Figure. Is it because I'm using two columns? How do I overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: @user75521: Nope. You must be loading some other package that is interfering. By the way, `8.5pt` is not a document class option for `article`.